# Is it possible to—on open—update links without prompt in Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a dashboard that others will use. When it's opened I want all links to updated. Without the prompt box appearing.

[image]

I can suppress the update box with the below, but will this still update the links ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
End Sub
```

Also if there is a broken link, I would like it to Continue without prompt, is that possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes the links will be updated.

From the offline help:

[image: Help Screenshot]

This code will suppress all the dialogs whilst forcing the links to update:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code to my spreadsheet but it's still appeared the prompt when opening the workbook
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuCCf.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1080609)